# Spring MVC dropping support for Apache Velocity. Alternatives?

Tags: spring, apache, velocity, freemarker, template-engine

At the most recent Spring conference, it was stated that Spring is dropping support for Apache Velocity.

Can anyone recommend an alternative template engine? Perhaps FreeMarker?

Comment: Why the downvote? I think is a valid question since Spring will delegate third-party dependence maintainance to this end.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view you could google this. I would go with Thymeleaf(http://www.thymeleaf.org/). You can checkout the http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html